# Hashed value regex

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords, bcrypt

I want like to capture value in the last part of the string between two tildes, `{TE,TAE}` and for that I thought of defining the pre look up which is hashed password also in between two
tildes:

```
{$2a$10$3Ncp3zpxqVp5VgXk/e2MkOTQQVA2lQ51ujQPzy7ra57QRQ.nvXbVq}.
```

So can anyone tell me what will be the regex for the hashsed password value so I can use this as my pre look up. Entire string is mentioned below.

I have tired

```
~isma407~$2a$10$3Ncp3zpxqVp5VgXk/e2MkOTQQVA2lQ51ujQPzy7ra57QRQ.nvXbVq~TE,TAE~
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: {?A-Za-z_0-9.{60}}?

Comment: Any attempts you've made should be edited into your question, so that future readers can see you've made the attempt.

Comment: ^\$2[ayb]\$.{56}$

Comment: Please, update your original question with the regexes you've tried. Putting them in comments doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ~ in the first string you provided as an example

if you want an example regex with the 2nd string, and we are assuming the length of the strings you are checking are relatively similar in length, you can capture it with the regex below

https://regex101.com/r/BlaCRC/2

```
.{3,65}.+~(.+)~
```